# How to fix Invalid Procedure in Query with datepart and datediff

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, charts

my codes seem to be saying the error "Invalid Procedure Call", I have looked to other threads and compare my query but I'm confused on what of part of my query is wrong
what will this code do is to get the weekdays and the DateofC=DateCreated and graph them that will show monday to sunday with the date created as the y-axis and count for the x-axis

```
Select count(PatientID), DatePart('ww',DateofC) from Patient Where 
       DateDiff('day',DateofC,Date()) Group by DateofC
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using datediff(), use with a comparison (= , > ,< , <>) operators, with where clause

```
SELECT COUNT(PatientID), DATEPART('ww',DateofC) 
FROM Patient 
WHERE DateDiff('day',DateofC,Date()) > 5 //something like this 
Group by DateofC
```

Comment: Noted, but still my error "Invalid Procedure Call" still enters as I run my query

Comment: @fytgdfasdsdfa can you clarify the purpose Date() in Datediff() ?? and is this query for mysql ?

Comment: to get the interval of my DateofC(DateCreated) from the lastest Date by day

Comment: i think issue is in date() function , try getdate() instead of date()  if you're in sql server or now() for mySql.